# The DBAdapter constructor is undefined

Tags: java, android, constructor

First Off: this is my first time ever looking at Java & the Android platform

I found a some sample code online that does some basic SQL database stuff using java and android.

I am receiving the "the constructor AssignmentTracker.DBAdapter(AssignmentTracker) is undefined" error.

(_ AssignmentTracker.java _) at this line:

```
public class AssignmentTracker extends Activity{
.....
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

}
```

The DBAdapter.java looks like this:

```
public class DBAdapter{
....
private final Context context;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
this.context = ctx;
DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
```

I've seen very similar questions on this site, but none of them have helped me so far.

Comment: What is DBHelper? This is class or variable? (you wrote it in uppercase, so it can be class). I`m sure that problem is in `DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);`  Can you post more code with declaring DBHelper?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I had another function/constructor named "DBAdapter" at the bottom of my AssignmentTracker.java file that was causing a conflict. I removed that and it all started working

Comment: Glad for you. Advice - do not declare variable starting from uppercase char - that`s for classes, not for variables. You can be confused later